# Is impossible to remove(not delete) an attribute from attribute set programmatically?

Tags: attributes

Has anyone tried to remove(not delete) unnecessary attributes from the Magento default set?
By default, Magento create an attribute set called "default" and it has a lot of unnecessary attributes. But we can not remove an attribute from the set if it is a system attribute.

I can retrieve all attribute in set by:

```
\Magento\Eav\Model\AttributeManagement::getAttributes($entityType, $attributeSetId)
```

after that, I don't have any ideal to check if it is a system attribute. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution.
Magento has a configuration to check if an attribute is system.

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Attribute\Config::getAttributeNames('unassignable');
```

After get all system attribute, i can remove other attributes in **eav_entity_attribute** table